# How to log all sql going through JBoss datasource with log4j

Tags: java, logging, jdbc, jboss, log4j

I've looked at [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/) (which does not support datasources), [p6spy](http://www.p6spy.com/) which seems to be what I am looking for but it has not been updated since 2003 which makes me nervous and lists only JBoss 3.x (we use JBoss 5), and [JAMon](http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/) which seems heavyweight for what I am trying to accomplish (a simple log of all SQL statements running through a JBoss application server).

I was hoping that JBoss itself would have a switch to log all the sql (as Websphere does) but I cannot find any documentation for it so that functionality might not exist.

Comment: FYI there's a much better answer if you're using Hibernate...  Other persistence providers have similar options as well. 

Stick in your persistence.xml file: 


    <properties>
      ...
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" /> 
    </properties>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like jdbcdslog might do what you're looking for.

http://code.google.com/p/jdbcdslog/

On the wiki page for this project there are notes on connecting it to and Oracle DataSource in JBoss.